# How to hide/Shoe Jframe in NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing

I am designing a project in NetBeans. For that I need to display a jdialog as a login window at first. But if I run the project both jframe and jdialog will appear. How can I hide jframe and how to set jdialog as a starting one in my project?

I wrote

```
LoginDlg.setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(false);
```

In construcor.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses. Either you're not making a modal dialog or your main method(s) are doing something werid

Comment: @MadProgrammer now i just edit my question. its my problem. Normally we can hide JFrame with setVisible(false) but in Netbeans how can i hide?

Comment: Make the dialog modal.

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

You want to make the `JDialog` a modal dialog, so that it will stop the execution of additional code.

In your program launch code, you want to show the dialog first, then, based on what the user does, show the main frame.

Alternatively, you could use a `CardLayout`, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details, which will allow you to switch the active view based on your needs

Comment: Thanks @madprogrammer i got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, show only the dialog. Then add a button or something(e.g timer) that hides the dialog, and add a listener to that dialog so when the dialog disposes the main frame is shown.

```
public class JavaApplication3{

private static JFrame f = new JFrame("alabala");
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JDialog d = new JDialog();
    d.add(new JLabel("pla"));
    d.setVisible(true);
    Timer t1 = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            d.dispose();
        }
    });
    t1.setRepeats(false);
    t1.start();
    d.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}